# Can I use Aero Glass with QXL (virt-manager)?

Tags: windows-7, qemu, aero, libvirt, virt-manager

I've made a Windows 7 VM with QXL as the display adapter. I installed the guest additions and the display adapter was properly showing up in device manager. I've tried changing the QXL settings to give it more VRAM but Windows still says it only has 16MB. Here are my QXL settings:

```
<video>
  <model type="qxl" ram="524288" vram="262144" vgamem="262144" heads="1" primary="yes"/>
  <alias name="video0"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
</video>
```

Here is a screenshot from the VM, showing Windows's explanation as to why Aero isn't working and the display adapter.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QXL was INTENTIONALLY designed to not give you a wddm 1.0 driver but only a DOD wddm 1.2 one. This way Windows 7 can only use a basic XP driver (to use aero glass you need a wddm 1.0 or 1.1 driver) since the wddm driver is for windows 8 and higher.